# Cumulative Sum Formula using new Excel Dynamic Array Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spill-range

I'm using the new Dynamic (ie Spill) formulas in Excel. I want a dynamic array that is the accumulation or running total of another dynamic array.

Let's assume I have the following dynamic data in `A1:A8`:

```
12
20
14
13
12
13
26
11
```

To find the differences in this array is trivial:

```
=OFFSET(A1#,1,0)-A1#

8
-6
-1
-1
1
13
-15
-11
```

But how do I get the running total using the new dynamic formulas?

```
12
32
46
59
71
84
110
121
```

Answer (score 11):

***Cumulative Sum Formula:** Using `LAMBDA()` helper functions `SCAN()` or `MAP()` or `BYROW()` --> Dynamic Spill Array Formulas, exclusively works with* <sup>**MS365 Current Channel Versions**</sup>

[image]

---

• **Method 1:** Formula used in cell `B1` --> Using `SCAN()`

```
=SCAN(0,A1:A8,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y))
```

---

• **Method 2:** Formula <sup>can be</sup> used in cell `B1` --> Using `VSTACK()` & `SCAN()`

```
=VSTACK(A1,SCAN(A1,A2:A8,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)))
```

---

• **Method 3:** Formula <sup>can be</sup> used in cell `B1` --> Using `LET()` with `SCAN()`

```
=LET(x,A1:A8, sum,LAMBDA(z,y,z+y), SCAN(0,x,sum))
```

---

• **Method 4:** Formula <sup>can be</sup> used in cell `B1` --> Using `MAP()`

```
=MAP(A1:A8,LAMBDA(x,SUM(A1:x)))
```

---

• **Method 5:** Formula <sup>can be</sup> used in cell `B1` --> Using `BYROW`

```
=BYROW(A1:A8,LAMBDA(α,SUM(A1:α)))
```

---

[image]

---

### Update: 11/15/2023

<kbd>SCAN()</kbd> function doesn't needs anymore <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> construct, only needs to reference single particular **`Excel`** Function directly. Here is an example below. Courtesy : Thanks To **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=SCAN(0,A1:A8,SUM)
```

---

<sub>NOTES: Formulas are updated in the post on 4/2/2024 and works with recent/current versions of `MS365`</sub>

---

Comment: Very slick. Lambda functions are a game changer for Excel.

Comment: Absolutely `LAMBDA()` is really game changer for Excel

Comment: Matrix functions are nice, but this should now be the accepted answer.

Comment: Vary nice font for Excel. What is it? (Also I love the answer)

Comment: The updates before `11/15/23` is `Biome` font while the one of `11/15/23` is `Daytona`

Answer (score 8):

Here's another approach using Matrix Multiplication

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(I3#) <= TRANSPOSE(ROW(I3#)))*I3#),SIGN(I3#))
```

Answer (score 7):

**New Answer** 2022-06-20

For a dynamic array in `A1` use:

`=MMULT(N(ROW(A1#)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1#))),A1#)`

If the dynamic array in `A1` has multiple columns, this returns the cumulative sum of each column, unlike my more complicated Original Answer.

**Original Answer** 2022-01-13

By using `SIGN(I3#)`, `chris neilsen`'s solution accumulates absolute values. To accommodate negative numbers, replace `SIGN(I3#)` with `1*(I3#=I3#)` in your cumulative sum:

`=MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(I3#) <= TRANSPOSE(ROW(I3#)))*I3#),1*(I3#=I3#))`

Alternatively, generate a dynamic array of ones with

`SEQUENCE(ROWS(I3#),,,0)` instead of `1*(I3#=I3#)`.

(I lack the reputation to comment.)

Comment: The following formula is just a little bit easier in may eyes, but still basically the same: `MMULT((ROW(D2#)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(D2#)))*1,D2#)`; by changing `<=` to `>=`, you can save a `TRANSPOSE`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way I've done it, but wondering if there's an easier/more efficient way to do it...

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1#,0,0,SEQUENCE(COUNT(A1#))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one solves a rolling twelve sum

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1#,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1#),1,0),0,12))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,INDIRECT(CELL("Address",A1)&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,SEQUENCE(NumberOfRows,0,0,1),0))))
```

Assume in the above that cell A1 contains the spill formula for the values you want to sum.  You can also use a helper column for SEQUENCE(), and if you did that in column B you would use:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,INDIRECT(CELL("Address",A1)&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,B1#,0))))
```

**THIS ALSO WORKS FOR A CUMULATIVE PRODUCT, IF YOU USE =SUBTOTAL(6,...)**

I found that the answers given above didn't work for me.

- For the matrix multiplication, it works for cumulative sums but it doesn't work for cumulative products. So my answer is a bit more generalised.
- For the earlier answers using SUBTOTAL(), for some reason I had to add a number to the values generated by SEQUENCE(). In my case, I had to add 3 which just seemed random. I could find no reason for having to add it, but without it the cumulative sum was out by 3 rows.

My answer doesn't seem to work for the PRODUCT() and SUM() formulae, only for SUBTOTAL(). I'd guess that PRODUCT() and SUM() haven't yet been changed to spill/array type formulae, but SUBTOTAL has.