# Running total from a named array formula in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, cumulative-sum, named-ranges

I want to create a named dynamic array formula that will give me a spill showing a *cumulative* (running) total of another array. I want one that I can enter into any cell in my workbook and get the same results.

I have the following named formulas:

1. **twelve:** `=ROW(OFFSET('CSM'!$A$1,0,0,12,1))`  **[EDIT:**  *I realised later it's simpler just to define it as* `=SEQUENCE(12)`**]** This generates an array of whole numbers from 1 to 12; I use it for a number of purposes, such as producing a list of months (`=TEXT(DATE(2023,twelve,1),"mmm-yy")`.
2. **FTE:**  `='CSM'!$B$3/12*(--(twelve=twelve))` This shows FTE's monthly salary (with cell B3 on sheet CSM providing the annual salary) over 12 months.

Now, if I enter `=FTE` on any cell, I'll get a 12-cell spill that shows the FTE's salary for each month.  That's fine, but what I *really* need is a named formula that when it spills will show the FTE's *cumulative* salary (a running total).

I can do this with a formula that links to a specific cell...for example, if I want my display to start in row 2 I use:
`=SUM((--(twelve<=ROW()-1))*FTE)`, and then drag the formula down the remaining 11 rows.  But I have to adjust this formula if I use it somewhere else--for instance, if I want to start my spill on row 10 I have to write `=SUM((--(twelve<=ROW()-9))*FTE)`.  I really want a named formula that I can use *anywhere on the sheet* without modification, that will give me a spill showing cumulative monthly salary.

I see you can do this using the `MMULT` function when the data are all on a worksheet (see [here](https://infoinspired.com/excel-formula/running-total-array-formula-in-excel/)), even when those data are a dynamic spilled array (see `=MMULT(ROW(A1#)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1#)),A1#)`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474792/cumulative-sum-formula-using-new-excel-dynamic-array-formulas)).  But when I use this approach on a **named** formula, I get a `#VALUE` error.  I think the error actually comes from the `ROW()` function--it looks like I can use `=ROWS(FTE)` (returns 12), but not `=ROW(FTE)` (which returns the error).

So my question is:  is there any way I can create a named formula that will give me a 12-month spill of FTE's cumulative salary by month?  Maybe using `SEQUENCE()` or `MMULT()` or something else...(We haven't got Lambda yet, by the way.)

***EDIT*** (in response to comments)**:**
For example, if B3=$75,000, putting `=FTE` into any cell will produce this (spilling over into cells below):

```
$6,369.86
$5,753.42
$6,369.86
$6,164.38
$6,369.86
$6,164.38
$6,369.86
$6,369.86
$6,164.38
$6,369.86
$6,164.38
$6,369.86
```

What I want is a cumulative sum (running total) of the above; that is:

```
$6,369.86
$12,123.29
$18,493.15
$24,657.53
$31,027.40
$37,191.78
$43,561.64
$49,931.51
$56,095.89
$62,465.75
$68,630.14
$75,000.00
```

As I mentioned, we haven't got Lamda at this point, or any of those newer formulae.

Comment: Show us some sample data and the expected output - then it is much easier to help you.

Comment: I hear you say spill. Would that mean you have access to SCAN()? `=SCAN(0,FTE,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))`

Comment: OK, edited original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured out a solution.  For whatever reason, it seems you can't use `ROW()` with named dynamic array formulas, but it turns out I don't need to.  I can simply use: `=MMULT((--(twelve>=TRANSPOSE(twelve))),FTE)` and I'll get the desired result (with 75000 being the value in B3):

```
6369.86
12123.29
18493.15
24657.53
31027.40
37191.78
43561.64
49931.51
56095.89
62465.75
68630.14
75000.00
```

I also found it useful to assign the above formula to a name, so I can conveniently enter it into any cell on the sheet and get the same output.

One more thing: I realised I can define the named formula **twelve** more simply by using `=SEQUENCE(12)`, though the `OFFSET` approach still works.  (Still getting used to some of there 'new' Excel formulas--not so new anymore, I guess.)  I edited original question to mention this.