# Excel running total / cumulative sum for each row of a dynamic array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays, cumulative-sum

i'm building an excel model using dynamic arrays which may expand horizontally or vertically depending on the inputs

Example of the array:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |

I'm trying to calculate the horizontal cumulative sum / running total for each row of an array. I've tried the Scan/Lamda combination explained here: [Cumulative Sum Formula using new Excel Dynamic Array Formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474792/cumulative-sum-formula-using-new-excel-dynamic-array-formulas)

This leads to a cumulative sum over the complete array, not for each individual row:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 10 |
| 15 | 21 | 28 | 36 |

Is it possible to achieve a cumulative sum for each row? The solution should look like this:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 10 |
| 5 | 11 | 18 | 26 |

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just employ some simple matrix multiplication?

`=LET(ζ,A1:D2,ξ,COLUMNS(ζ),MMULT(ζ,N(SEQUENCE(ξ)<=SEQUENCE(,ξ))))`

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work. Didnt think of MMULT().

Answer (score 2):

I initially thought that you could do it by using Scan nested within Byrow, but this results in a 'does not support nested arrays' error.

You can do it fairly easily using a combination of Makearray and Index:

```
=MAKEARRAY(
    2,
    4,
    LAMBDA(r, c,
        SUM(
            INDEX(sheet1!A1:D2, r, 1) : INDEX(sheet1!A1:D2, r, c)
        )
    )
).
```

[image]

It appears that you cannot define the range in a Let statement and pass it through to the lambda like this:

```
=LET(
    range, Sheet1!A1:D2,
    MAKEARRAY(
        2,
        4,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            SUM(INDEX(range, r, 1) : INDEX(range, r, c))
        )
    )
)
```

results in

[image]

But you can write the first formula more generally by defining A1:D2 as a named range e.g. range1

```
=MAKEARRAY(
    ROWS(range1),
    COLUMNS(range1),
    LAMBDA(r, c, SUM(INDEX(range1, r, 1) : INDEX(range1, r, c)))
)
```