# Sorting/ordering values from smallest to biggest in an array

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, split, vlookup, flatten

I have a formula like this  : `=ArrayFormula(sort(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,MATCH(E1,$A$1:$A$10,0))))`

```
in columns A:B:

    a   1
    b   2
    c   3
    d   4
    e   5
    f   6
    g   7
    h   8
    i   9
    j   10
```

and

```
 the data to convert in E:H
a   c   f   e
f   a   c   b
b   a   c   d
```

I get the following results using the above formula

```
in columns L:O:
1   3   6   5
6   1   3   2
2   1   3   4
```

My desired output is like this:

```
1   3   5   6
1   2   3   6
1   2   3   4
```

I'd like to arrange the numbers from smallest to biggest in value. I can do this with additional helper cells. but if possible i'd like to get the same result without any additional cells. can i get a little help please? thanks.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(E1:H3&"×​"&ROW(E1:H3)), "​"), 
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0),,9^9)), "×")))
```

[image: 2]

or if you want numbers:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(E1:H3&"×​"&ROW(E1:H3)), "​"), 
 "select max(Col1) group by Col1 pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0),,9^9)), "×")), A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

To sort by row, use `SORT` `BYROW`. But unfortunately, nested array results aren't supported in `BYROW`. So, we need to `JOIN` and `SPLIT` the resulting array.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(BYROW(your_formula,LAMBDA(row,JOIN("",SORT(TRANSPOSE(row))))),""))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using Makearray with Index to get the current row and Small to get the smallest, next smallest etc. within the row:

```
=ArrayFormula(makearray(3,4,lambda(r,c,small(index(vlookup(E1:H3,A1:B10,2,false),r,0),c))))
```

[image]

Or you could change the order (might be a little faster) as you don't need to vlookup the entire array, just the current row:

```
=ArrayFormula(makearray(3,4,lambda(r,c,small(vlookup(index(E1:H3,r,0),A1:B10,2,false),c))))
```

It's interesting (to me at any rate) that you can interrogate the row and column number of the current cell using Map or Scan, so this is also possible:

```
=ArrayFormula(map(E1:H3,lambda(cell,small(vlookup(index(E1:H3,row(cell),0),A1:B10,2,false),column(cell)-column(E:E)+1))))
```

Thanks to @JvdV for [this insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006511/cant-pass-a-range-to-a-lambda-using-let-and-makearray-functions) (which may be obvious to some but wasn't to me) shown here in Excel.