# MAXIFS doesn't work as expected invoked inside MAP using names from LET

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Just for testing purpose, I have the following formula showing different scenarios at the same time via `HSTACK`:

```
=LET(item, "A", colA, A2:A7, colB, B2:B7, ux, UNIQUE(colA),
  noMapOut, MAXIFS(colB, colA, item),
  mapOut1, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, MAXIFS(B2:B7, A2:A7, item))),
  mapOut2, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, MAXIFS(colB, colA, item))),
  HSTACK(noMapOut, mapOut1, IFERROR(mapOut2, "#CALC!"))
)
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

From the result:

- `noMapOut`: Returns the max of the group `A`, as expected. This scenario uses the names defined in the `LET` function. It demonstrate `MAXIFS` can work with names representing ranges defined in the `LET` function, when it is not invoked inside `MAP`.
- `mapOut1`: It works. This scenario doesn't use the names defined in `LET`
- `mapOut2`: Returns `#CALC!` error (I encapsulated it with `IFERROR` because otherwise it returns `#CALC!` for the entire `HSTACK` output). This scenario uses the same ranges as in `mapOut1`, just referring to them as names defined in the `LET` function. **This is my real scenario**, the other ones are just for testing purpose and to be able to isolate the problem.

Therefore the issue seems to be a combination of factors. The unexpected error appears when 1) using `MAXIFS` inside 2) `MAP` and 3) names from `LET` function are used representing the ranges.

**Is there any explanation for that? Am I doing something wrong or it is just another Excel bug?**

Here is the input data:

| Group | Values |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| A | 20 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 30 |
| C | 20 |

**Note**: I am not looking for a workaround, just trying to understand unexpected result of `mapOut2` scenario. The workaround to get the expected result can be `mapOut1` scenario or just using `FILTER` instead of `MAXIFS`:

```
=LET(rng, A2:B7, colA, INDEX(rng,,1), colB, INDEX(rng,,2), colAUx, UNIQUE(colA),
  MAP(colAUx, LAMBDA(item, FILTER(colB, (colA=item)
    * (colB = MAX(FILTER(colB, colA=item))))
  ))
)
```

It returns the expected result:

```
20
10
30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might consider it a bug or, given their documented limitations, one might just add this to the list of [racon-function](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) limitations, i.e. by substituting

```
MAX((colA=item)*colB)
```

for

```
MAXIFS(colB, colA, item)
```

the 3rd column of your formula will evaluate correctly.

Similar behaviour can also be seen with `SUMIFS`, further incriminating that family of functions, i.e.

```
LET(colA,A2:A7,colB,B2:B7,ux,UNIQUE(colA),MAP(ux,LAMBDA(item,SUMIFS(colB,colA,item))))
```

produces a `#CALC` error, whereas the non-racon version

```
LET(colA,A2:A7,colB,B2:B7,ux,UNIQUE(colA),MAP(ux,LAMBDA(item,SUM(colB*(colA=item)))))
```

does not.

Comment: Thanks @SpectralInstance. The problem with this workaround: `MAX((colA=item)*colB)` is that it works **only** for positive numbers. For example if all `colB` values for `ColA` equal to `item` are negatives. It returns `0`. If you know upfront they are going to be all negative values, then you can use:  `-MAX((colA=item)*(-colB))`, but if you cannot guarantee the sign of the numbers you cannot use it. Similar problem for `MIN` instead of `MAX`

Comment: @DavidLeal I wasn't explicitly trying to provide a workaround (since you didn't want one) but I think you can employ `AGGREGATE` for this purpose (albeit a more verbose formula), i.e. `=LET(item, "A", colA, A2:A7, colB, B2:B7, ux, UNIQUE(colA),
  noMapOut, MAXIFS(colB, colA, item),
  mapOut1, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, MAXIFS(B2:B7, A2:A7, item))),
  mapOut2, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, AGGREGATE(14,6,(POWER(10,LOG10(colA=item))*colB),1))),
  HSTACK(noMapOut, mapOut1, IFERROR(mapOut2, "#CALC!"))
)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to have the entire picture of this problem. First, it is not tied to a specific [RACON function](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) nor to a specific array function such as `MAP`. The following question: [Using name variable from LET produces #VALUE! inside MAP using SUM with the range defined as INDEX : INDEX [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595902/using-name-variable-from-let-produces-value-inside-map-using-sum-with-the-rang) even though the problem was found in a different scenario, it seems to have the same root cause. As @Jos@Woolley pointed out in his question:

> It appears that range variables defined via `LET` external to the `LAMBDA`
> to which they are being passed are first 'evaluated' to their
> corresponding array.

Here would the approach using @JosWoolley's suggestion from the other question, defining the variables inside `MAP` function via an internal `LET`:

```
=LET(item, "A", colA, A2:A7, colB, B2:B7, ux, UNIQUE(colA),
  noMapOut, MAXIFS(colB, colA, item),
  mapOut1, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, MAXIFS(B2:B7, A2:A7, item))),
  mapOut2, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, LET(x, A2:A7, y, B2:B7, MAXIFS(y, x, item)))),
  HSTACK(noMapOut, mapOut1, IFERROR(mapOut2, "#CALC!"))
)
```

Another question: [Can't pass a range to a lambda using Let and Makearray functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006511/cant-pass-a-range-to-a-lambda-using-let-and-makearray-functions) addresses the issue with `MAKEARRAY` function too.

I posted the question in **Microsoft Tech Community**: [MAXIFS doesn't work inside MAP using names from LET](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/maxifs-doesn-t-work-inside-map-using-names-from-let/m-p/3681425/highlight/false#M171470) and I got another workaround:

```
=LET(item, "A", colA, LAMBDA(A2:A7), colB, LAMBDA(B2:B7), ux, UNIQUE(colA()),
  noMapOut, MAXIFS(colB(), colA(), item),
  mapOut1, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, MAXIFS(B2:B7, A2:A7, item))),
  mapOut2, MAP(ux, LAMBDA(item, MAXIFS(colB(), colA(), item))),
  HSTACK(noMapOut, mapOut1, IFERROR(mapOut2, "#CALC!"))
)
```

so the idea here is to define the ranges via as-user `LAMBDA` functions:

```
colA, LAMBDA(A2:A7), 
colB, LAMBDA(B2:B7)
```

Then it can be used inside `MAP`.