# Excel merge cell content up to blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a big excel list, and I want to merge, the content of multiple cells, comma separated, in a single cell.

But ...
-the number of these content-cells are unknown.
-these content-cells also hold duplicate values, which also need to be sorted out.

Unfortunatly Iam no Excel-Expert, and also dont know VBA.
I guess something like this *should* be possible using VBA.
If its possible at all with formulars, I still cant answer that.

I tried to find some answers about this over the last days, all over the net.
But I cant seem to find any information which could help me here with this special case.
Maybe I use the wrong searchterm here.

*Let me try to explain it in more detail:*
A "dataset" in this list has multiple rows.
Between each "dataset" there is an empty row.
The number of rows can vary. (see example)

Iam trying to get a comma separated list, of all values, up to the next empty row,
without any duplicates.

| What I have | What I want to achieve |
| --- | --- |
| < blank > | 15x15cm, 20x20cm, 30x30cm |
| 15x15cm | 15x15cm |
| 15x15cm | 15x15cm |
| 15x15cm | 15x15cm |
| 20x20cm | 20x20cm |
| 20x20cm | 20x20cm |
| 30x30cm | 30x30cm |
| < blank > | 10x10cm, 15x15cm, 20x20cm, 30x30cm |
| 10x10cm | 10x10cm |
| 15x15cm | 15x15cm |
| 20x20cm | 20x20cm |
| 30x30cm | 30x30cm |
| 30x30cm | 30x30cm |
| ... | ... |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(A1:$A$14),0)+ROW(A1)-1,1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(A2:$A$14),0)+ROW(A1)-1,1)))),A1)
```

Formula to be pasted in B1 and dragged down. Keep in mind that this formula is written for dataset in A1:A13.
If used in other "place" need to change not only `A1`, `A1:$A$14`, `ROW(A1)`, `A2:$A$14`, but also -1 in `+ROW(A1)-1`

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the data I need based on your formular, and accepted your answer! I guess that Davids idea would be more flexible and would require less adjustment than this approach. But for my usecase your answer works great!

Answer (score 1):

The following approach doesn't require to use a [Volatile functions](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function). In cell `C2`, put the following formula:

```
=LET(A, LAMBDA(A2:A14), n, ROWS(A()), s, SEQUENCE(n), f, IF(A()="", s,-1), 
  b, VSTACK(FILTER(f, f>0), n+1), MAP(A(), s, LAMBDA(aa, ss, LET(start, 
  XLOOKUP(ss, b, b, -1), IF(start<0, aa, LET(end, MIN(FILTER(b, b>start)),
  TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(INDEX(A(),start+1):INDEX(A(),end-1)))))))))
```

Here is the output:

[image: excel output]

The use of user `LAMBDA` function `A()` is to be able to use a [RACONs functions](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) or ranges like this: `INDEX:INDEX` inside an array function such as `MAP`. Check the @DavidLeal's answer from this question: [MAXIFS doesn't work as expected invoked inside MAP using names from LET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510691/maxifs-doesnt-work-as-expected-invoked-inside-map-using-names-from-let).

The main idea is to identify the index position of the blank cells in column **A**. The name `b` has such positions plus the `n+1` for the last one. Then on each iteration of `MAP` function, we check for blank cell index position (`s`) and if so we identify `start` and `end` index positions for doing the concatenation, otherwise we return the corresponding value of column **A** (`aa`).

Comment: Thank you David for your Input. Unfortunatly I could not get your formular to work in my document. I even tried multiple times to rebuild your formular manually, but I always got some invalid errors and couldnt figure out what was wrong. Iam sure that this was entirely my fault though!

Comment: Thanks @LWS-Mo probably some excel version conflict, what is your excel version? share an editable link to your file, so I can take a look at it. I you can obviously.

Comment: Iam using the german, Office365 version of Excel.
So I had to "translate" some formulars. I did this manually and also tried out an Excel-Translator for this.
I think the translation itself was not the problem, because I got no errors regarding the used formulars.

Iam sorry I cant link the document directly, cause there maybe some sensible data. 
And to strip it down it would require some work which I cant do in the moment.

Comment: I see, I meant to share a mockup or sample file. Here you have a [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ih2Qc1fMi98qLj_uC?e=Iel0cK) to my sample file, so you can check it works. We are using the same version, so probably there is another reason. Would you share also the error you are getting? Thanks