# how to return the row number of all rows from a bridge table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bridge table and a row of labels like below

[image]

[image]

How can I return the row number of each label (A, B, and C). The expected output is list below.

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Shouldn’t the results for C1 etc be 7, 8, 9? Why is C3 na?

Comment: Try matc() plus a constant or row().

Comment: The match appears to use Category not SubCategory @SolarMike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#:%7E:text=Important%3A%20Press%20Ctrl%2BShift%2B,before%20you%20enter%20the%20formula.) (entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter). Later versions of Excel partic. 365 support more concise formulations than shown below where I use SMALL and IF. Essentially, create an array of 1|0 matches to the Category, use IF to filter out 0s, and use the row the formula is in to return the next smallest match.

Set-up

[image]

Formula in D2 then dragged across and down. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to ensure formula is an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ROW($B$2:$B$9)*--($B$2:$B$9=D$1)>0,ROW($B$2:$B$9)*--($B$2:$B$9=D$1)),ROWS($C$2:$C2)), NA())
```

You could use same idea with MATCH

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$2:$B$9,D$1,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$9)*--($B$2:$B$9=D$1)),ROWS($C$2:$C2)), NA())
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the row number not the index position within an array. This solution spills the entire result all at once. You can use the following formula in `D1` cell:

```
=LET(B, B2:B9, ux, UNIQUE(B), rows, DROP(REDUCE("", ux, LAMBDA(ac,u, 
 HSTACK(ac, FILTER(ROW(B2:B9), B=u)))),,1), VSTACK(TOROW(ux), rows))
```

[image: excel output]

We use the `DROP/REDUCE/HSTACK` pattern to concatenate each column per iteration of `REDUCE`. Check my answer to the following question: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691) for more details.

If you are curious why I don't use the name `B` in the `ROW` call, inside the `LAMBDA` function of `REDUCE`. The reason is that `ROW(B)` produces `#VALUE!`. Probably related to the same possible bug as it was documented in this question: [Using name variable from LET produces #VALUE! inside MAP using SUM with the range defined as INDEX : INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595902/using-name-variable-from-let-produces-value-inside-map-using-sum-with-the-rang), check @JosWoolley's answer. For example the following works, but it is not worth it to introduce an additional `LET`:

```
=LET(B, B2:B9, ux, UNIQUE(B), rows, DROP(REDUCE("", ux, LAMBDA(ac,u, LET(
  colB, B2:B9, HSTACK(ac, FILTER(ROW(colB), B=u))))),,1), VSTACK(TOROW(ux), rows)
```

or a more elegant solution is to create a `LAMBDA` function (`B`) that refers to the range `B2:B9`:

```
=LET(B, LAMBDA(B2:B9), ux, UNIQUE(B()), rows, DROP(REDUCE("", ux, LAMBDA(ac,u,
 HSTACK(ac, FILTER(ROW(B()), B()=u)))),,1), VSTACK(TOROW(ux), rows))
```

Check my answer to the question: [MAXIFS doesn't work as expected invoked inside MAP using names from LET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510691/maxifs-doesnt-work-as-expected-invoked-inside-map-using-names-from-let) for more information. The above approach has a lower maintenance cost because you need to update the range just in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Textsplit & Textjoin functions

=--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(D$1=$B1:$B9,SEQUENCE(ROWS(D1:D9)),"")),,",")

[image: Result]

or try with Filter func but the formula seems lengthy..

=FILTER(IF(D$1=$B1:$B9,SEQUENCE(ROWS(D1:D9)),"#"),IF(D$1=$B1:$B9,SEQUENCE(ROWS(D1:D9)),"#")<>"#")

[image: Result2]