# Multi-level numbering based on another column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to change the existing numbering to multi-level numbering using excel formulas, example below.

[image]

The solutions found are too difficult for me to process. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't be something like this with the formula if i am not wrong here: `=A1&"."&COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)` and with dynamic spill array `=BYROW(A1:A15,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,A1:A15,x&"."&COUNTIF(INDEX(y,1):x,x))))` or with `MAP()` `=MAP(A1:A15,A1:A15,LAMBDA(x,y,x&"."&COUNTIF(INDEX(y,1):x,x)))`

Comment: The first solution meets my needs. Thanks again

Comment: Since your data is grouped, you could use the far more efficient running count presented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75773001). With a few minor modifications (instead of `3,` use `6,Data&"."&`), it would boil down to this: `=LET(Data,A2:A16,Data&"."&SCAN(0,Data=DROP(VSTACK("",Data),-1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b,a+1,1))))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if i have understood correctly and based on my comments, one could use the following formulas based on their excel versions:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=A1&"."&COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=BYROW(A1:A15,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,A1:A15,x&"."&COUNTIF(INDEX(y,1):x,x))))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=MAP(A1:A15,LAMBDA(m,LET(n,A1:A15,m&"."&COUNTIF(INDEX(n,1):m,m))))
```

---

**Edit : 3/25/2023**

As suggested by **[VBasic2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008)** Sir, one can also use the following alternatives for more efficient output.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E1`

```
=BYROW(A1:A15,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,A1,x&"."&COUNTIF(y:x,x))))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `F1`

```
=LET(Data,A1:A15,Data&"."&SCAN(0,Data=DROP(VSTACK("",Data),-1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b,a+1,1))))
```

---

Comment: You could improve with this: `=BYROW(A1:A15,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,A1,x&"."&COUNTIF(y:x,x))))`.

Comment: Ah yes, works nice I shall update both the formulas as well.