Excel Formula to Create a Running Count of a Horizontal List of Values
=LET(Data,verticalArray,
SCAN(0,Data=DROP(VSTACK("",Data),-1),
    LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b,a+1,1))))

This formula works well for a vertical array, but I can't formulate a working counterpart if the dataset was horizontal (e.g., A1:Z1).
The intended result is to replicate a COUNTIF(A1:Z1, A1) formula and return an array (note that COUNTIF(A1#, A1) does not work, and COUNTIF($A1:A1, A1) copied across is not an array).
Attempted but failed:
=LET(data, A1#, SCAN(0, data=DROP(HSTACK("", data), -1), LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b, a+1, 1))))
=LET(data, A1#, SCAN(0, data=TRANSPOSE(DROP(VSTACK("", data), -1)), LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b, a+1, 1))))
=LET(data, A1#, SCAN(0, data=DROP(TRANSPOSE(VSTACK("", data)), -1), LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b, a+1, 1))))



Reference post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75772794/calculating-a-running-count-without-using-offset

can you share a screenshot of your data and expected result? COUNTIF($A1:A1, A1) copied across does not generate the same result of the post you've shared.

This formula generates a horizontal running count that resets to 1 every time the value is different:
=HSTACK(1,SCAN(1,A1:K1=B1:L1,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c,a+1,1))))


This formula generates a running count for each value without resetting (it's equivalent to =COUNTIF($A1:A1,A1) dragged across):
=MAP(A1:L1,LAMBDA(_,COUNTIF(A1:_,_)))



Wow, I've never even seen the map function before. The solution is even cleaner than I intended. Huge kudos!

Here are two more alternative way which can accomplish the desired output using SCAN() as well as MAP():


• Formula used in cell A2
=SCAN(0,A1:L1=HSTACK("",DROP(A1:L1,,-1)),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,1)))


Or, The following gives you a running count while the top one will render an output where it resets to one, everytime there is a change in the sequence of similar values.

• Formula used in cell A5
=MAP(A1:L1,LAMBDA(α,SUM(N(α:A1=α))))


